# What is the name of the bifurcation with normal form $\dot{x} = \mu x$?

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

Consider the equation
$$\dot{x} = \mu x$$.

The origin is stable for $\mu < 0$ and unstable for $\mu>0$. Is there a name for this bifurcation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a name for this kind of bifurcation. Generally, Bifurcation theory is used for nonlinear differential equations. Your equation is a simple linear equation. This implies that the stability of the system is global and the system is actually pretty uninteresting :D. For $\mu>0$ we have an unstable system (I can say system because the system is linear). For $\mu=0$ we have a system with infinitely many equilibrium points. And For $\mu <0$ we have exponential asymptotic stability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am surprised that there is no name for this trivial bifurcation! As you said there's not much going on but it's the simplest bifurcation one could study, that should be enough to give it a name. Maybe "boring" bifurcation will do?

Comment: @rpa: Lol "boring" would really be a nice name for this :D.

Comment: @MachineLearner Meh, bifurcations in all linear system are kinda boring and lame :D

Comment: @Evgeny: You must admit that his one is particularly boring :).

Comment: @MachineLearner Okay, fair enough, I admit :)